# Unable to display a Modal popup controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to display a modal popup in my application. I do see it being it displayed but the frame is not correct and the direction arrow is not visible

Here is the code that i am using to display popup on clicking a bar button

```
    @IBAction func filterBarButtonAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {


    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "MapViewController", bundle: Bundle(for: type(of: self))).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FilterModal")
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    vc.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.bounds
    vc.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender as? UIView
    vc.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.up;
    vc.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
    self.searchResultsController.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

[The current view appears like this][1]

What changes do i need to make to display popup with arrow directions on clicking a UIBarButton

**Edit**: as per Pierce's suggestion when i changed to

```
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
```

[I see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnzkD.png)

[I want to display some like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRpnc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working now after i added

```
    public func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller:UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    print("adaptive was called")
    return .none
}
```

Thanks to Pierce, setting modalPresentationStyle as popup was the correct approach